# Xamarin ZipAlign not found

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When hitting the play button in Xamarin I receive this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Users\OP\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\\tools\zipalign.exe" is invalid. (MSB6004) (HelloWorld)
```

When looking at the file path I don't see a zipalign.exe in the folder (also the double \\ seems mysterious).

I just installed Xamarin so maybe it was a bad installation?

Can I turn off zipalign?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found the solution in the [Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/61483#Comment_61483):

> The latest SDK from Google, released today, moved some things around.
>   We're preparing an update to handle the new locations
>
> You can work around the issue by finding the android-sdk directory on
>   your system, then copying zipalign from the build-tools/19.1.0
>   directory to the tools directory

Comment: This is now fixed in Xamarin 3.1.223 - http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_3/xamarin.vs_3.1/

Comment: Linger from hours behind this issue, working .. Thanks

Comment: @WickedW it is not fixed. still happening. every time need to clean obj,bin,tmp folders restart Vs to run in release more

Answer (score 13):

The Jason suggestion is good, but...

You need to copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\zipalign.exe not in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

but in

C:\Users\yourfolder\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools

(need to see hide file)

By :)

Edit: 
Jason comment is:
Found the solution in the Xamarin forums:

The latest SDK from Google, released today, moved some things around. We're preparing an update to handle the new locations

You can work around the issue by finding the android-sdk directory on your system, then copying zipalign from the build-tools/19.1.0 directory to the tools directory

Edit 2 :
Bug resolved with Xamarin 3.1.223

http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_3/xamarin.vs_3.1/

> **Fixes** 
>    Fixes a regression introduced by Android SDK Tools r23 and Android Build-tools r20 that changed the path of the zipalign tool.

Comment: For mac, copy /Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macos/build-tools/19.1.0/zipalign to /Library/Developers/Xamarin/android-sdk/macos/tools

Comment: In a Windows Command Prompt, copying it did resolve it for me. `copy %localappdata%\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\zipalign.exe %localappdata%\Android\android-sdk\tools`

Answer (score 0):

StefanoM5 has the right idea, only if you installed it with the option of "Just for me".

If you installed it for "Everyone on this computer" then it is moving it into

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools**

Answer (score 0):

if you are not finding the location of zipalign.exe, then go to ->android sdk tools .
 then go to -> android SDK build-tools , if it is not installed , then install it and copy it to the location C:\Users\yourfolder\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools.