# Error in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

When I create an android application it reports the following error (formatted for readability):

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
Error MSB6004: The specified task executable location
"C:\Users\Rashid\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\\tools\zipalign.exe" 
is invalid. (MSB6004) (newTest)
```

Comment: probably you find your answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441710/xamarin-zipalign-not-found) post

Answer (score 0):

A search for the error ID, [`MSB6004`](https://www.google.com/search?q=MSB6004), suggests that [the fix for this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441710/xamarin-zipalign-not-found) is to update Xarmin to at least version 3.1.223.  The linked question also discusses copying files in `C:\Program Files` or wherever Xarmin is installed, but in theory that should not be necessary.